# How avoid this error (Structure)

Tags: c

I am trying construct a structure and there is function which returns a pointer of that type

This is my sample code

```
struct Word
 {
     char data[10];                         //my structure
     struct Word *nextWord;
     struct Word  *lastWord;
 };

 Word* addWord(Word* top, Word* newNode)   // my function declaration
```

I have created a structure word and just below it , i have declared an function.its showing an error that **'expected declaration specifiers or ... before Word '**.why??

Comment: this `Word*` --> `struct Word*`

Comment: If you want to be able to use `Word` as a type, as in, `Word * addWord(...)` then you need a `typedef` for `Word`: `typedef struct { ... } Word;`. What you have right now is just declaring a `struct` with a *tag* `Word`. It doesn't define `Word` as an identifier representing a type.

Answer (score 0):

Change your declaration from

```
Word* addWord(Word* top, Word* newNode)   // my function declaration
```

to

```
struct Word* addWord(Word* top, Word* newNode)   // my function declaration
```

Notice the `struct` keyword. This is because in C, structure instances have the following syntax:

```
struct struct-name instance-name;
```

Or, you could define your struct like this

```
tyepdef struct Word
 {
     char data[10];                         //my structure
     struct Word *nextWord;
     struct Word  *lastWord;
 };
```

The `typedef` keyword allows us to write just `Word *w` instead of `struct Word *w`.

Comment: Your `typedef` won't allow `Word` to be used as a type. It still only defines `Word` as a structure tag. You would need `typedef struct { ... } Word;`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `struct` to the struct name when creating a new variable type. That is `struct Word *newWord;`, read more information here [C struct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_(C_programming_language))

Change this

`Word* addWord(Word* top, Word* newNode)`

to this

`struct Word* addWord(struct Word* top, struct Word* newNode)`

Answer (score 0):

if you are using C++ program then you need not to declare the struct keyword but as you are in C program then in the function add a struct key word i.e.
struct Word* addWord(struct Word* top, struct Word* newNode);